# Fluent NHibernate Relationships that Share Columns

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

I have a database that shares columns for relationships. Here is the condensed table structure

```
Order
----------
OrderId int IDENTITY

OrderLine
----------
OrderId int NOT NULL
OrderLine int NOT NULL

OrderNote
----------
NoteId uniqueidentifier NOT NULL
OrderId int NOT NULL
OrderLineId int NULL
```

Basically the OrderNote table is shared between Order and OrderLine. If the OrderLineId column is null, the note belongs to the order. If the OrderLineId column is present, the note belongs to the order line. Here is what my classes look like:

```
class Order {
    int OrderId {get; set;}
    IList<OrderLine> Lines {get;}
    IList<OrderNote> Notes {get;}
}

class OrderLine {
    int OrderLineId {get; set;}
    Order Order {get; set;}
    IList<OrderNote> Notes {get;}
}

class OrderNote {
    Order Order {get; set;}
    OrderLine Line {get; set;}
    Guid NoteId {get; set;}
}
```

If the OrderNote.Line is null, the note belongs only to the Order. If OrderNote.Line is not null, the note belongs to the order and the line. Here is what my mappings look like:

```
class OrderClassMap {
    Id(x => x.OrderId).Generated.Identity();
    HasMany(x => x.Lines).Inverse().KeyColumn("OrderId");
    HasMany(x => x.Notes).Inverse().KeyColumn("OrderId");
}

class OrderLineClassMap {
    CompositeId().KeyReference(x => x.Order, "OrderId").KeyProperty(x => x.OrderLineId);
    HasMany(x => x.Notes).Inverse().KeyColumns.Add("OrderId", "OrderLineId");
}

class OrderNoteClassMap {
    Id(x => x.NoteId).Generated.Assigned();
    References(x => x.Order).Column("OrderId");
    References(x => x.Line).Columns("OrderId", "OrderLineId");
}
```

When I try to save a new OrderNote, I get an error saying "Invalid index 11 for this SqlParameterCollection with Count=11. How do I correctly model and map this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are talking about only 1 note per order and 1 note per orderline? If so, map the note as a column in order and also a note column for the orderline. The will make a big impact on performance having less joins and simple queries - (otherwise you need left outer joins and coalesce statements).

If you can have multiple notes per order and orderline then create seperate ordernote and orderlinenote value objects. Depends on the needs of having more that 1 note per order/orderline. Would lean towards 1 note per entity rather as this is the easiest and offers best performance and a ordernote and orderlinenote are different in terms of the domain design.

```
class Order {
    int OrderId {get; set;}
    IList<OrderLine> Lines {get;}
    string Note {get;set;}
}

class OrderLine {
    int OrderLineId {get; set;}
    Order Order {get; set;}
    string Note {get;set}
}
```

or

```
class Order {
    int OrderId {get; set;}
    IList<OrderLine> Lines {get;}
    IList<OrderNote> Notes {get;}
}

class OrderNote {
    int Id {get;set}
    Order Order {get; set;}
    string Note {get; set;}
}

class OrderLine {
    int OrderLineId {get; set;}
    Order Order {get; set;}
    IList<OrderLineNote> Notes {get;}
}

class OrderLineNote {
    int Id {get; set;}
    OrderLine OrderLine {get; set;}
    string Note {get;set}
}
```

Comment: There needs to be multiple notes per Order and OrderLine. The reason it's designed this way is that the Order actually contains all of the note objects even the ones that belong to the lines. So just to be clear. There is no way to share columns like this in NHibernate?

Comment: It looks like there is no way around this with NHibernate. I was hoping that because OrderLine and OrderNote use a composite key that had a reference back to the OrderId, that I wouldn't have to create a duplicate column. I ended up creating a duplicate column for the OrderLine reference.